# External ping fails on Linksys router

Tags: router, ping, dmz

When I try to ping my server from somewhere other than my local network, if finds the host, but returns as a lost packet.

Screenshot from http://tools.pingdom.com: http://cl.ly/1I1c3K0z3Y1I2c3x3R3Z

I have my server plugged into a Linksys WRT610N router, and when I bypassed the router and went strait to the server the ping worked perfectly.

So, the problem lies with the Linksys router, but I cannot find anything that would fix it. I have DMZ set to forward everything to my server.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this reply](http://homecommunity.cisco.com/t5/Wireless-Adapters/Enabling-ICMP-for-a-specific-IP-address-WRT610N/m-p/324224#M27139) in the Linksys UK forum, all you need to do is to Uncheck **Filter Anonymous Internet Requests**.

.

[image]

.

[Source of screenshot](http://portforward.com/routergui/)

Comment: I tried that earlier, and it doesn't work. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Linksys's are blocking ICMP requests by default, anyway You can disable it in some of models

Comment: Do you know of a suitable router that doesn't block them?

Comment: Euhm... No... Linksys does not block ICMP by default...

Comment: @TiZion Linksys does for this router evidently